# Horizontal lines appear when viewing site with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I view this site on Internet Explorer 11 (running on Windows 7), everything renders fine. But when I start scrolling, I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, several horizontal lines appear in the previously hidden area that are the same color as the side borders. This does not appear on any other Stack Exchange site that I regularly visit, nor does it appear on Travel Meta.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with just me or if all Internet Explorer 11 users have this problem, but I figured I would bring it up just in case.

Comment: IE11 working for me, Windows Server 2012.  It *might* be the rendering with your graphics card, but we'll wait for the experts to have a look I guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible fix for you on [Microsoft.com](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2d444cb8-0a86-4452-8f40-d58497bf6022/ie9-displaying-multiple-horizontal-lines?forum=ieitprocurrentver).

1. Go to Control Panel –All Control Pane Items - Internet Options.
2. Choose Advanced tag, click “Reset…” button, click OK in the pop-up box.
3. Click OK to close Internet Options, then restart Internet Explorer

Also consider this article [How to disable or enable software rendering in IE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2528233) which may cause the issue.

Comment: The problem fixed itself on its own without me doing anything. But it seems that reseting Internet Explorer like you suggested would be the right fix for if it happens again.